# Why am I receiving a "unepxected tLABEL, expecting ')' error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On line 4 I am receiving error message `"unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'`.

module Placeholder
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

```
 def self.image_generator(height: , width:)
 "http://via.placeholder.com/#{height}x#{width}"
 end
```

end

Comment: Delete the `:` after each argument, unless you want to use keyword arguments, and you forgot the values.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 extra "`:`" not sure why...

```
module Placeholder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.image_generator(height , width)
    "http://via.placeholder.com/#{height}x#{width}"
  end
end
```

Unless you want to pass key word arguments. that would look like this:

```
module Placeholder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.image_generator(**args)
    "http://via.placeholder.com/#{args[:height]}x#{args[:width]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I replicate his code, it throws `NoMethodError`.

Comment: hmmm interesting. Did you just test it?

Comment: In pure Ruby, not Rails.

Comment: Let me also try that out

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to use keyword arguments, you don't need the colons:

```
class Foo
  def image_generator(height: '60', width: '60')
    "http://via.placeholder.com/#{height}x#{width}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
p foo.image_generator # arguments aren't passed, it uses the "default" values
p foo.image_generator(height: 640, width: 480) # arguments are passed, it uses them

class Foo
  def image_generator(height, width)
    "http://via.placeholder.com/#{height}x#{width}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
p foo.image_generator # arguments not passed: it raises "wrong number of arguments"
p foo.image_generator(640, 480) # arguments are passed, it uses them
```

Comment: Great solution as usual @SebastianPalma ;)